# Correct pattern / approach to avoid / minimize duplicate functionality based on runtime condition

Tags: c#, design-patterns, constants, dry, c#-5.0

Given this situation:

```
public const string _constantString_Kind1 = "a constant string";
public const string _constantString_Kind2 = "other constant string";

[SomeSealedAttribute(_constantString_Kind1)]
public static int A_Kind1(); // this was just A()

[SomeSealedAttribute(_constantString_Kind2)]
public static int A_Kind2(); // this was just A() as well,
                             // doing the same thing


public int CallA () {
  return B.SomeRuntimeBooleanFlag ? A_Kind1() : A_Kind2();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid any of these:

- declaring `A_*` twice.
- a method bootstrapping the call
- two consts for one runtime check

This seems possible at meta level with T4 templates or using Relefection, but I prefer avoiding those.

Is there some better pattern I can follow to exercise DRY in this scenario?

Comment: I think your question would get a good answer at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NimaAra if it weren't hypothetical code, sure. Code Review wants to see real working code, not example-ish boiled-down stub code.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is this for a DllImport with say x86 and x64 versions of an unmanaged assembly? I would create an interface and choose at runtime which to initialize a singleton instance with.

Comment: @mikez, exactly. The only reason why I didn't wanted it to call out straight is because of all the bureaucracy around that subject in .NET Framework and Mono communities (`DllImport` etc.). Plus I don't want to p/invoke `kernel32`, because I am targeting cross platform (including BSD and such). I have actually wrapped both in two internal classes (`MyExternsx86` and `MyExternsx64`), redefined all the externs twice and created bootstrap methods for each with neural names.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the two attributes, but as the two methods have different meaning, there should be two methods in your code. To respect DRY, you can then refactor both methods into a private method.

But sure, this code has a smell, but that probably has to do with the framework used (why you need those attributes there in the first place?)